# JAVAFX button action to call a function of other class

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a project using javafx. I am using netbeans IDE. I had created many classes. When a button is pressed, a function from other class has to be worked. How to make it working ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Java 8:

```
button.setOnAction(e -> anInstanceOfYourOtherClass.yourMethod());
```

Prior to Java 8:

```
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        anInstanceOfYourOtherClass.yourMethod();
    }
});
```

Comment: My problem is that all my classes extends the Application class. Also there is start() method in every class. How to call the start() method of a class from other class ?

Comment: @TominJacob Why do all your classes extend Application? You should only have one entry point (Application subclass).

Comment: Will you explain it a little further ?

Comment: @TominJacob You should (probably) have one class that extends Application with a start method: that is where your application starts. But your other classes, whatever they do, should (probably) not extend Application. Without seeing some of your code it is difficult to be more specific. The best thing to do would be to post [a simple example that shows the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok. Could you show me code of a class that do not extends Application ?

Comment: @TominJacob Not sure I understand. 99% of classes in Java don't extend Application... `class MyClassThatDoesNotExtendApplication { }`

Comment: Here is part of my class                              public class WelcomePage extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

// Use a border pane as the root for scene
        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
        
        border.setTop(addVBox());
        border.setLeft(addVBox1());
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(border,700,450);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
        
    }

Comment: It's easier if you edit your question and add the relevant information and code in there. But there is only one class in your example, can you show the other class that you need to call?